# Resources raw folder localize in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-resources

I'm Xamarin Developer

I want to play *.mp3 or *.wav file in the localized application

so I divided the file like that

[image]

and I implement code in dependency service like

```
  public void OnePlaySound()
    {
        _mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(context, Resource.Raw.wavone);

        _mediaPlayer.Start();
        _mediaPlayer.Completion += delegate
        {
            if (_mediaPlayer != null)
            {
                _mediaPlayer.Stop();
                _mediaPlayer.Release();
                _mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        };
    }
```

but _mediaPlayer always returns null..

is there any solution to use the localizing raw files?

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your description that you want to use MediaPlayer to play an audio file in the  Resource/Raw folder using dependencyservice in Xamarin.Forms. Here is  an example:

First, create interface named IPlayAudio in .Net standard library project(shared code).

```
public interface IPlayAudio
{
    void playaudio();
}
```

Then create one class that implements IPlayAudio in the Android platform, the platform implementations must be registered with the DependencyService, so that Xamarin.Forms can locate them at runtime.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PlayAudiomethod))]
namespace playvideo.Droid
{  
public class PlayAudiomethod : IPlayAudio
{
    private MediaPlayer _player;
    public void playaudio()
    {
        _player = MediaPlayer.Create(MainActivity.mac, Resource.Raw.MyAudio);
        _player.Start();
    }
}
}
```

For MainActivity.mac, please create static member called "mac" in  MainActivity and set it after the call to LoadApplication.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static MainActivity mac;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);      
        LoadApplication(new App());
        mac = this;

        
    }
  
}
```

Now you can play audio from the Xamarin.Forms shared code.

```
  private void mediaplayer_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IPlayAudio>().playaudio();
    }
```

Note: please set xxx.mp3 **Build Action** as **AndroidResource**.

Comment: Thank you for your sincere answer. is it possible to find a localized raw folder automatically? I played an audio file when just one raw folder, but I have to divide the folder for localizing. then I tried the media player doesn't work....

Comment: @cocoadrinker About localized audio file on Android, you can try to take a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows#localize-images-on-android